# I am tring to make a todo list in javascript but when i try to count how many items are unchecked it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a todo list that can detect how many items are unchecked, but I'm not really sure how to make that happen. For each item I create a 'li' tag and then append an 'input' tag to it. But I'm not sure how to make the code know how many are unchecked.

I have no idea how to count how many items are unchecked.

```js
let todos = []


function reflectToHTML(i) {
  let count = 0
  let listItem = document.createElement('li'),
    itemCheck = document.createElement('input')
  itemCheck.type = 'checkbox'
  itemCheck.id = 'check' + todos.length

  listItem.append(itemCheck, i['text'])

  document.getElementById('todo-list').appendChild(listItem)
  document.getElementById('item-count').innerText = todos.length


}

function createTodo() {
  let newTodo = {
    text: '',
    checked: 0
  }
  newTodo['text'] = prompt('Item description')
  if (newTodo['text'] != null) {
    todos.push(newTodo)
    reflectToHTML(newTodo)
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container center">
  <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
  <div class="flow-right controls">
    <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
    <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
  </div>
  <button class="button center" onClick="createTodo();">New TODO</button>
  <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### global variable and change listener

You can add an event listener listening for changes for the checkbox.
You can use a global variable which gets track of the unchecked boxes.

```
let countUnchecked = 0;
```

Initially its *value is 0* when you add a new checkbox its value *increases by one*. When the box gets selected it increases by one and when it gets deselected it decreases by one.

```
itemCheck.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (itemCheck.checked) {
      countUnchecked--;
      document.getElementById('unchecked-count').innerText = countUnchecked;
    } else {
      counter++;
      document.getElementById('unchecked-count').innerText = countUnchecked;

    }
```

```js
let todos = []
let countUnchecked = 0;

function reflectToHTML(i) {

  let count = todos.length
  let listItem = document.createElement('li'),
    itemCheck = document.createElement('input')
  itemCheck.type = 'checkbox'
  itemCheck.id = 'check' + todos.length

  listItem.append(itemCheck, i['text'])
  itemCheck.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (itemCheck.checked) {
      countUnchecked--;
      document.getElementById('unchecked-count').innerText = countUnchecked;
    } else {
      countUnchecked++;
      document.getElementById('unchecked-count').innerText = countUnchecked;

    }
  })
  document.getElementById('todo-list').appendChild(listItem)
  document.getElementById('item-count').innerText = todos.length
  countUnchecked++;

  document.getElementById('unchecked-count').innerText = countUnchecked;

}

function createTodo() {
  let newTodo = {
    text: '',
    checked: 0
  }
  newTodo['text'] = prompt('Item description')
  if (newTodo['text'] != null) {
    todos.push(newTodo)
    reflectToHTML(newTodo)
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container center">
  <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
  <div class="flow-right controls">
    <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
    <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
  </div>
  <button class="button center" onClick="createTodo();">New TODO</button>
  <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener just for the `<ul>` element and not for each `type='checkbox'` element ex:

```js
document.querySelector("#todo-list").onchange = function() {
  document.querySelector("#unchecked-count").textContent = this.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").length;
}
```

so here on each change we get the node list of the unchecked checkbox elements of that ul element and set the counter the length of that list.